# How to watch my headset mic working?

Tags: windows-10, microphone, mute, ventrilo

Using a Logitech H540 USB headset, Ventrilo 3.0.8, and Windows 10.

When I'm gaming with my friends, my headset seems to mute by itself. I often don't notice until someone says they can't hear me. Pressing the mute button turns the sound back on, but I think pressing the volume buttons may turn it off.

Since the mute indicator light doesn't work at all, it would be useful if I had a visual indicator on-screen. Like a bar that shows my voice level, or a simple "mute" light that actually works.

Is there anything in Ventrilo that does this? Or in Windows 10? Or some kind of utility app?

Comment: Try to set your mic in Control Panel [sound settings](https://oxen.tech/blog/using-sounds-settings-control-panel/)

Answer (score 0):

Update driver at first.

Then, click sound icon on task bar:

Move to Communications tab, select Do nothing.

Move to Recording tab, Right-click your device and select Properties, Advanced, uncheck the Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device option.

Apply, OK.

Besides, try to change the format of the Microphone on Advanced interface

Comment: I'll try that. Meanwhile, do you know a way I can visually see if the mute is on? That was my original question.

Comment: Could you explain how to "change the format of the Microphone on Advanced interface"?